# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos(x^2+2x)}{1-\cos(x^2+x)}$ without L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

Could you help me with this limit please:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{1-\cos(x^2+2x)}{1-\cos(x^2+x)}
$$

I know that with L'Hopital is easy but I want to do it without that theorem. I have already tried converting it  to:
$$
 \frac{2\sin^2(x^2/2+x)}{2\sin^2(x^2/2+x/2)}
$$
or expanding the sin of the sum of two angles:
$$
 \frac{\sin(x^2/2)\cos(x)+\sin(x)\cos(x^2/2)}{\sin(x^2/2)\cos(x/2)+\sin(x/2)\cos(x^2/2)}
$$
but I can not advance further than that and eliminate the indetermination 0/0. I would really appreciate if you could help me please.

Comment: *Hint*: Divide by $\frac{x^2/2+x}{x^2/2+x/2}$ (or rather its square).

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... [You asked this question before.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4244643/409) Please note that re-posting a question is not the appropriate way to draw more attention to it (or to circumvent closure). Rather you should simply edit the original to improve its quality. (Editing will "bump" a question to the top of the Unanswered queue, so you get the benefit of posting a new question without cluttering the site with duplicates.) ... Since this version has received answers and the previous one hasn't, you should delete the previous one to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+2x)}{1-\cos(x^2+x)} &= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sin^2(\frac{x^2+2x}{2})}{2\sin^2(\frac{x^2+x}{2})} \\
&= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2(\frac{x^2+2x}{2})}{\left(\frac{x^2+2x}{2}\right)^2}\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{x^2+x}{2}\right)^2}{\sin^2(\frac{x^2+x}{2})}\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{x^2+2x}{2}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{x^2+x}{2}\right)^2} \\
&= 1\cdot1\cdot\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\left(\frac{x^2+2x}{2}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{x^2+x}{2}\right)^2}}\\
&= \lim_{x\to0}{\frac{x^2(x+2)^2}{x^2(x+1)^2}}\\
\\
&=4
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Well since
$$\forall x\in \mathbf{R}: \quad \frac{1-\cos(x^{2}+2x)}{1-\cos(x^{2}+x)}=\csc^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)\sin^{2}\left(x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)$$
and using that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\csc^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)\sin^{2}\left(x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)=4$$ so the answer is $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(x^{2}+2x)}{1-\cos(x^{2}+x)}=4.$$